# помогите с проммисом

Tags: javascript, promise

код функции qw менять нельзя можно менять только колбек

```
var qw = (func)=> {
    var val = 123;
    if (func(val) === false ) {
        console.log('good');
    }
    else {
        console.log('bad');
    }
}

qw((val)=> {
    // типа бекенд который сравниват значение val и val2
    setTimeout(()=> {
        var val2 = 123;
        if (val == val2) {
            var result =  'результат сравнения';
        }
    },500)
    return false // как сюда вернуть результат сравнения 
})
```

Comment: никак *(9 символов нужно...)*

Comment: Ваша qw синхронна. Получить асинхронный результат в ней низя.

Answer (score 1):

Ближайшее, что можно предложить - использовать механизм [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).
Он позволяет писать асинхронный код, как синхронный(за исключением маркеров async/await)

```js
const qwLikeSync = async function (f) { 
  // Мы всё ещё пишем return, но возврат произойдёт в виде резольва промиса
  return await f(123) ? 'bad' : 'good';
};
const qwAsync = f => f(123).then(res => res ? 'bad' : 'good');

const func = num => val => new Promise(ok => setTimeout(() => ok(val === num)));

const badFunc = func(123);
const goodFunc = func(321);

qwAsync(badFunc)
  .then(res => console.log('abad', res));
qwAsync(goodFunc)
  .then(res => console.log('agood', res));

qwLikeSync(badFunc)
  .then(res => console.log('sbad', res));
qwLikeSync(goodFunc)
  .then(res => console.log('sgood', res));

// Аналогично можно завернуть и вызов такой функции
(async function() {
  let res = await qwLikeSync(goodFunc);
  console.log(res);
})()
```